# convert to es6 without breaking the functionality of code

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to convert my working code into Es6 without breaking. Can anyone help me. I have tried to convert it into es6 but something went wrong and my code didn't work. Must of the time I have used es5 and so I am looking for any kind of help. The following program allows user to draw on canvas
I really appreciate your answer.

```js
var flag = false,
  prevX = 0,
  currX = 0,
  prevY = 0,
  currY = 0,
  dot_flag = false,
  ratio;


function init(fieldId) {
  //fieldId are multiple Ids, but I get here one at a time
  let canvas = document.getElementById("can-" + fieldId);
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  ratio = 400 / 800;
  canvas.width =
    document.body.clientWidth < 800 ? document.body.clientWidth : 800;
  canvas.height = canvas.width * ratio;

 

function draw(ctx) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
  ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
  ctx.strokeStyle = x;
  ctx.lineWidth = y;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function findxy(res, e, c) {
  let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  if (res == "down") {
    prevX = currX;
    prevY = currY;
    currX = e.clientX - c.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    currY = e.clientY - c.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    flag = true;
    dot_flag = true;
    if (dot_flag) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillStyle = x;
      ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
      ctx.closePath();
      dot_flag = false;
    }
  }
  if (res == "up" || res == "out") {
    flag = false;
  }
  if (res == "move") {
    if (flag) {
      prevX = currX;
      prevY = currY;
      currX = e.clientX - c.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      currY = e.clientY - c.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      draw(ctx);
    }
  }
}



function resizeCanvas(canvas) {
  ratio = 400 / 800;
  canvas.width =
    document.body.clientWidth < 800 ? document.body.clientWidth : 800;
  canvas.height = canvas.width * ratio;
}
```

```css
img {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: please explain more about: 'code not worked'

Comment: your current code will not work in the code snippet section.

Answer (score -1):

There's a package called **Lebab** for converting es5 to es6.
[Lebal documentation](https://github.com/lebab/lebab)